# Win10 allow incoming ICMPv6 - firewall is behaving weirdly

Tags: windows, windows-10, nat, windows-firewall, icmp

I finally got it working but I'm a bit confused still.

Has anyone an idea why this approach (netsh) doesn't work on win10?
[technet forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb095c94-1565-4fc8-9bf1-3a21a44a4365/add-icmpv4v6-echo-request-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V6 echo request" protocol="icmpv6:8,any" dir=in action=allow
```

Because the GUI approach works (for some reason):
[gui approach](https://noobient.com/2018/08/02/passing-icmpv6-on-windows-defender-firewall/)

The only obvious difference to me: the second approach doesn't include the firewall profile public, but that can't be the reason, right?

PS: If you want to test this as well, than you might have to allow ping6 in your router firewall as well (including your temporary ipv6 if you want tests like this one: http://www.ipv6-test.com/ to show "Reachable" instead of "ICMP filtered")

Answer (score 6):

For others that ran into the same issue described above. ICMPv6 echo requests are code 128, not 8 as they are in ICMPv4. That needs to be reflected in the rule.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V6 echo request" protocol="icmpv6:128,any" dir=in action=allow
```

Notice `icmpv6:128` instead of `icmpv6:8` in OP's command.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that *Public* is required. Even in the GUI approach, if Public is not selected, you get ICMP filtered.

Answer (score -1):

BTW, windows 10's default icmpv6 allow rule limits source-ip-address to same network, click properties and allow all source addresses, then you wont need to create manual rules.